# How to maintaining listView (java/android)

Tags: android, listview, restore

I have a listview in the SubActivity of my app.. but when I go from the subActivity to the main Activity and i try to return to the subActivity, the item of the listView disappear.. how to fix this problem?
also if I close my app and i restart it, my listview is empty... why?

my MainActivity:

```
final ArrayList<String> listCron = new ArrayList<String>();
....
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id) {
        case R.id.history:
            Intent history = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HistoryClass.class);

            history.putStringArrayListExtra("history", listCron);
            startActivity(history);
            break;

        default:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

my SubActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.history_main);

    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    Intent i = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> cronologia = i.getStringArrayListExtra("history");

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.viewCron);
    if (cronologia.isEmpty()) {
        cronologia.add("No operations");
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_layout, cronologia);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HistoryClass"
        android:label="@string/history">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Put the code in your question on how you get to the SubActivity and how you go back to Main Activity. Also check the Log for errors. Also WTF do you mean (also if I destroy my app and I create it,  my listview is empty)  what do you mean by destroying it??

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: for destroy I mean "to close" the app ahah.... i don't have any error log... but my list view is empty when i close and restart my app

Comment: @karaokyo I don't understand the difference between    `getSharedPreferences()`  and  `getPreferences()`

Comment: `getPreferences` calls `getSharedPreferences` with the activity name as the preference file name. I would typically use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences` for a default app-wide  preference file. Also, shared preferences are typically not recommended for storing list view items.

Comment: @karaokyo so what is the best method for storing list view items?

Comment: @karaokyo but in my app the items of listview are only local string..

Comment: @karaokyo i use listview as the history of a calculator..

Comment: I don't understand what point you're trying to make.

Comment: I want that my history remains after i close and i restart my app @karaokyo

Comment: Yeah, I got that. And you're trying to say that SQLite wouldn't work for some reason because your listview is local strings, which makes no sense.

Comment: Ok.. i think I should study SQLite to make a simple listview.. :( @karaokyo